# alternatives for this forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, foreach, splice

I have some code which loops through a user array using forEach. And within that loop i again use forEach to loop through their price alerts. It looks like this

```js
  user_data.users.forEach((user, index) => {
    if (user.id == id) {
      user.price_alerts.forEach((alert, alert_index) => {
        if (alert.symbol == symbol) {
          //remove alert
          user.price_alerts.splice(alert_index, 1);
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

But the problem with this is instead of removing ALL the matches with the 'SYMBOL' it just removes one.
How do i fix this ?  Thanks in advance <3

Comment: `Array.prototype.filter()`

Comment: Yes, i've read but i'm not sure how to implement it in this case. Could you help me figure it out?

Comment: `user.price_alerts.filter(alert => alert.symbol !== symbol);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need remove all elements which are not satisfying some condition, then try to use `filter` method:

```
let result = user.price_alerts.filter(alert => alert.symbol !== symbol);
```

UPDATE:

```
user.price_alerts = user.price_alerts.filter(alert => alert.symbol !== symbol);
```

Comment: can i do it without assigning it to a new variable like

`user.price_alerts.filter(alert => alert.symbol == symbol);`

(since i want to remove all matching symbols when condition is met)

Comment: filter doesn't modify the existing array it returns a new one with only elements that match the predicate.  You can do something like user.price_alerts = user.price_alerts.filter(...) to replace the existing alerts

Comment: @KautilyaKondragunta testpossessed is right. Please, see my updated answer